# Evaluate $\sum_{i=0}^{20} \frac{i}{10}(\frac{1}{i} + \frac{1}{1+i} + ...+ \frac{1}{20})$

Tags: summation, solution-verification

Would the answer be 11.5? I simplified the above expression to $\frac{1}{10}\{1(1) + \frac{1}{2}(1+2) +. .. + \frac{1}{20}(1+2+...+20)\}$ =$\frac{1}{10}\sum_{k=1}^{20} \frac{k+1}{2}$ and thus got 11.5

Comment: Numerically verified.

Comment: When i=0 what happens?

Comment: Just to to clarify, your case is much easier when you simplify it to $\frac{1}{20 } \sum_{k=1}^{20} {k+1} = \frac{1}{20}( \frac{ 21\cdot 22}{2}-1)$

Answer (score 1):

I'll put $n$ for $20$
and start the sum at $i=1$
since the inner sum is not well defined
at $i=0$.

The sum is

$\begin{array}\\
s(n)
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{i}{n/2}\sum_{j=i}^n \dfrac1{j}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n i\sum_{j=i}^n \dfrac1{j}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^ji \dfrac1{j}
\qquad\text{since } j \ge i, i \le j\\
&=\dfrac{2}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n\dfrac1{j} \sum_{i=1}^ji \\
&=\dfrac{2}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n\dfrac1{j}\dfrac{j(j+1)}{2} \\
&=\dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n (j+1)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{n} (\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}+n)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{n} \dfrac{n(n+3)}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{n+3}{2}\\
\end{array}
$

For $n=20$ this is
$\dfrac{23}{2}
=11.5
$.

Comment: $11.5$ instead of $11.55$

Comment: I fixed it. Now agree.

Comment: Sum starting at 0 has a problem, so I started at 1.

Comment: I don't understand the $3$rd to last expression. Doesn't the sum from $j=1$ to $n$ equal $\frac {n(n+1)}{2} -1$?

Comment: No. Sum goes to n+1 so it is $(n+1)(n+2)/2-1 = (n^2+3n+2-2)/2 = (n^2+3n)/2$.

Comment: I understand now, it goes to $j+1$. The only thing left I'm trying to understand is the first line .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116449/discussion-between-marty-cohen-and-derek-luna).

Comment: Thank you $+1$.